# Debugging Python in VS code not working

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In am trying to debug my python script in VS Code but the debugger is not even starting. The blue bar keeps on loading after clicking the green play button and the bar below which was supposed to turn Orange doesn't change and is blue as it is.

What I tried?
1. Adding the path in launch.json file. 
Here is my launch.json file.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "localhost"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}"
    },
```

I have configured the path correctly in Windows advanced settings and in VS code workspace setting as well.

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

If I try to run the debug in **Python: Current File** or **Python: Terminal(Integrated)**, I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_small_test\CSV_parser>cd c:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_small_test\CSV_parser && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe C:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.4.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py c:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_small_test\CSV_parser 49947 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput c:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_small_test\CSV_parser\test.py "

'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

And when I try to run it in **Python: Terminal(external)** , the IDE sits IDLE.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just had to add the path "C:\Windows\System32" in the path variable in environmental variables under Advanced System settings.

Comment: Any advice for Mac users?

Comment: never had the chance to use Mac but maybe try running `echo $PATH` and look for the missing pieces. Good Luck